# Is there any way we can get the server certificate issuer name behind the proxy that alters the certificate

Tags: ssl, server, proxy, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Is there any way we can get the server CA certificate issuer name behind the proxy. I believe my organization has a proxy which inspects the TLS and alters the certificate. I would like to get original certificate issuer name of the server before it gets altered. Any code in python would be helpful

I searched in internet an I couldn't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the TLS intercepting proxy is explicitly providing the information about the original issuer (like in some HTTP header or in the newly created certificate) there is no way to determine what certificate the proxy has seen. And TLS intercepting proxies usually do not provide this information.

To determine the original server certificate one need to access the server through a connection which is not affected by the TLS intercepting proxy. This does not guarantee though that one will get the exact same certificate as the proxy got though, since a domain might be reachable by multiple IP which have different certificates installed or the provided certificate might differ based on client side TLS settings (i.e. server ECDSA or RSA certificate depending on offered ciphers).